# Am I being redundant on my class properties definition?

Tags: typescript

I am learning Typescript by creating an discord.js bot and I don't know if the next piece of code is redundant:

```
import Discord from 'discord.js';

export default class Bot {
  client: Discord.Client = new Discord.Client();
}
```

Is that a good way to define my client property or should I do it like this instead:

```
client = new Discord.Client();
```

They both work just fine but I don't know which one is a better practice.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are valid and it depends on your specific use case.

TypeScript has [type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html). This means when initially assigning the value it can infer the value of `client`.

If it's likely your `client` will change and you want to ensure it has a specific API/type definition it doesn't hurt to explicitly define the type definition. In this scenario, it is unnecessary and duplicative but it makes it clear to any future readers what you intend the type to be.